# Helper File or View File

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a standard HTML table that displays information about all users. The last column in the table displays button actions that can be used for the user. This is a column that gets repeated over several different tables of data so I am interested in knowing is this something I should use a helper for or should I make a view out of this column?

Comment: go for helper you will just call one method over and over in different tables

Comment: post some code! otherwise the answers will be too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a helper. You can add the helper in `/application/helpers/some_helper.php`

Your `some_helper.php` could look like this:

```
<?php  if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if(!function_exists('user_actions'))
{
    function user_actions($user)
    {
        // do something with $user
        // this function needs to "return" and not "echo"
    }
}
```

If you are going to be using this helper throughout your application it might be best to [autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) it. That way anytime you need to use a function in your helper, you just run it like a normal PHP function. I am assuming by your question that yours might look something like this:

```
<td><?php echo user_actions($user); ?></td>
```